# Why do we need datastructures other than HashMap

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, stl, hashmap

Map (or HashMap) takes Constant time for Insert, Remove and Retrieve. While all other data structures which I know so far, do not take constant time and their time for above operations depends on the size of input.

So, why do we need all other data structures ever ? Isn't HashMap is universal data structure ?

Comment: `Isn't HashMap is universal data structure?` - no, it doesn't preserve elements order and will not allows for duplicates  and will not let you access elements by index and ...

Comment: Try learning Go, where maps are basically the only built-in data structure (aside from arrays). You *can* just use maps for things; but the novelty of implementing a set with a map *yet again* wears off pretty quickly.

Comment: Where did you learn that Insert, Remove and Retrieve take constant time? [`This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and as you can't supply a hash-function, but the type's build-in is used…

Comment: Try storing ranges in a hash map. Or finding the item that's closest to a particular value. So you might have keys 5 and 8, and if somebody searches for key 7, you return 8 because it's the closest. Map and HashMap are great for looking things up by an exact value, but that makes up a small part of how programs access things. There are many things that a HashMap or similar structure just can't do, or can't do efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

The *Map* performance isn't free, the cost is memory and complexity.

Other data structures exists for all the cases where you don't care about performances and when you don't need to access to just one element of the collection.

For example, if you have a given list of elements string, and the only use you have in your code is to print out exactly this list of elements, the better choice is to use an array of strings.

Another example, could be the order of the elements. If you care about the order in which your elements have to be, than a *Map* is not the data structure you should use, as the order is not guaranteed, so you have to sort each time you need.

Those are just two examples, there are many others for each data structure that exists.

Comment: "where you don't care about performances" you use different data structures when you *do* care about performance. For example, you can emulate a `List<Value>` with a `Map<Integer, Value>` (like JS does with arrays). But the performance would be a lot worse than using `ArrayList`.

Comment: @AndyTurner esp if you want the indexes to change on insert or remove.

Comment: @AndyTurner I meant performances in access to the value, as the OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap shouldn't be used when

- a plain Java object would do the job. Java objects are type safe and more efficient.
- when you need a sorted collection.
- when the key is an Enum.
- when the index is an `int` starting at 0.
- when the key might change.
- when you want concurrent access.
- when you need any ordering or priority in your collection.
- when you need a set of things (i.e. there are no values)